# ie gradient + background-image

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Is there any way to make ie (7,8) display a gradient AND a background-image on the same div?

The only way I got it working (but only almost) was by using two filters, one for the gradient and one using the AlphaImageLoader - but of course, then you can't position the image.

Declaring a background-image and gradient filter doesn't work, because it simply won't render the image - only the gradient.

Is there any (preferably non-js) solution to this?

If not, I'll have to resort to using a background image for the gradient as well, which isn't quite as nice but won't make much of a difference either...

Comment: You could make one in your favorite image editing program, or use two divs of the same dimensions, one with the gradient and an opacity and one with the background image.

Comment: Thanks, those are both possible solutions but I'm trying to avoid 1) unnecessary markup and 2) having to use huge pngs (1040x308+).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that adding a little unnecessary markup is the lesser of the evils here. Either that, or let IE-users live without the gradient.

Oftentimes getting your design to work is a trade-off between semantics, performance, standards and pixel perfection. Accepting that fact was hard for me, but it's made me a better front-end developer - I can work faster, and I can make decisions about what metric is important in a given case.

Comment: I agree, if IE users persist in using an outdated, awful demon browser, then they get what they use.

Comment: Unfortunately not an option in a corporate environment in case you like keeping your job.

Comment: @StephanKristyn Sounds like a toxic environment if a gradient is something to lose a job over.